# Indented longtable

Tags: tables, indentation

My ltxtable is indentated on both sides and I don't want the indents.
My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ltxtable, filecontents}
\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents}{longtable.tex}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{|X|m{20ex}|m{5ex}m{5ex}|}
\hline
\textbf{Verlaufstyp} & \parbox{16ex}{\textbf{ergänzende Beschreibung}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Probanden}} \\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
1.\,monophasisch zur Vollremission & 17,2 Monaten Dauer & 50 \newline 10 &  10,0\,\% \newline 2\,\% \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{longtable.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image: example with indentation]

Comment: Almost duplicate, because I need to use `\documentclass{scrreprt}` while `\extracolsep` is part of `\documentclass{article}`. As soon as I know how to load the package for `\extracolsep` it should be analogous.

Comment: The macro `\extracolsep` isn't defined in the `article` document class. Instead, it's defined in the LaTeX kernel itself (as `\def\extracolsep#1{\tabskip #1\relax}`, in case you're curious). It should be usable by anyone using the `scrreport` document class.

Answer (score 0):

Well and trying to make a good example I just prepared the question and by chance I got after over 3 h of searching an answer.

It's perhaps not the best one, but it's working. I replaced the `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Probanden}}` by `\textbf{Probanden} &`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ltxtable, filecontents}
\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents}{longtable.tex}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{|X|m{20ex}|m{5ex}m{5ex}|}
\hline
\textbf{Verlaufstyp} & \parbox{16ex}{\textbf{ergänzende Beschreibung}} & \textbf{Probanden} & \\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
1.\,monophasisch zur Vollremission & 17,2 Monaten Dauer & 50 \newline 10 &  10,0\,\% \newline 2\,\% \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{longtable.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]